# Replace underline in multiple XML files

Tags: linux, string, xml

In a directory with several XML files (there may be hundreds of files) I have a field called `<import_url>`. In this field it can happen that a URL has an underscore.

I would like this underscore to be replaced by a hyphen, such as in the example below:

**in_natur**

```
<import_url>archiv/in_natur/der-beitrag-name.html</import_url>
```

Should be

```
<import_url>archiv/in-natur/der-beitrag-name.html</import_url>
```

How can I search and replace this in linux command line?

For reference, here's the entire XML file

```
<article id="6577889" type="article">
  <author>
    <forename>Hans</forename>
    <surname>Wurs</surname>
    <email>Hans.Wurs@gmail.com</email>
    <title></title>
    <position></position>
    <authorId>23262452</authorId>
  </author>
  <headline>Der Titel des Beitrags</headline>
  <body>
    Fringilla placerat elementum ratione? Illum blandit wisi adipisicing at sunt, proin minim. Quibusdam similique soluta, viverra 
    excepteur sem justo commodo? Congue eiusmod, temporibus doloribus urna pulvinar. Quibusdam elementum ante pretium nostra atque, 
  </body>
  <date>
    <createdDate>2020-04-30T10:44:35+00:00</createdDate>
    <publishingDate>2020-04-30T00:00:00+00:00</publishingDate>
  </date>
  <metaDescription>Faucibus quidem quo, nostrud voluptates nunc mollitia curae</metaDescription>
  <import_url>archiv/in_natur/der-beitrag-name.html</import_url>
  <taxonomy type="channel">
    <channel id="Archiv:Natur" parent="Archiv">Natur</channel>
 </taxonomy>
</article>
```

Comment: I'm sure someone will come up with a good sed regex expression, but the key here is to a) figure out how to edit the files then b) run this against all files in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a properly formed XML document you can use an XML parser/editor to modify it

Source file, `/tmp/xml`

```
<article>
  <-- other sections omitted -->
  <import_url>archiv/in_natur/der-beitrag-name.html</import_url>
</article>
```

Modification

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '/article/import_url' --expr 'translate(., "_", "-")' /tmp/xml
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<article>
  <-- other sections omitted -->
  <import_url>archiv/in-natur/der-beitrag-name.html</import_url>
</article>
```

Since the matching uses XPath you can match on `//import_url` if you prefer.

You can also add `--inplace` if you really want to edit your files in-place. I don't generally recommend that though; it's better to write to a temporary file and if that's successful then (and only then) replace the source.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to the xmlstarlet solution, here's how you do it using Saxon's Gizmo utility:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Gizmo -s:/tmp/xml
/>update //import_url translate(., '_', '-')
/>save /tmp/xml
/>quit
```

https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!gizmo

To process all the files in a directory, you can run this XSLT 3.0 transformation:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" expand-text="yes" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="import_url">
  <xsl:copy>{translate(., '_', '-')}</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection('file:///my/input/directory?recurse=yes')">
    <xsl:result-document href="file:///my/output/directory/{tokenize(document-uri(),'/')[last()]}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```